# Excel Macro Vlookup between two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I  have started a simple macro to clean up a report. I need to add a vlookup and am having a hard time figuring out what direction go in, if I should use match, or vlookup expression, and how to work around the file names being dynamic and changing from week to week.

I am more of a SharePoint workflow writer, and tend to lean toward needing a variable of sorts to store the file name (of the second opened sheet) in, to recall later in the vlookup, but am not sure if this is the proper thought, or exactly how to execute. As I am a beginner you will see I have wrote this line by line, with many comments, verses necessarily condensing steps.

Goal:

Take audit report that will already be open by user, run macro to clean up file, select previous version of file (as select by user in dialog box), and vlookup columns, return result in original formatted document, paste values of vlookup, clean up any #n/a values, close source file after look up, save destination file.  Vlookup information is in comments within code where it should be written.

```
Sub AuditRptCleanup()

 

    'Verify Correct File Is Open

    If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*Audit*" Or ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*AuditReport*" Or   

    ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*audit*" Or ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*auditreport*" Then

    On Error GoTo ErrorFileIncompatiable:

   

    'Verify Macro has not ran on Workbook Previously

    If Cells(1, 1).Value = "Product Number" And Cells(1, 2).Value = "Prod Type" Then

    MsgBox "Macro has already been used on this workbook"

    Exit Sub

    End If

           

    'Select Starting Cell

    Range("A1").Select

   

    'Unmerge all Cells in Worksheet

    ActiveSheet.Cells.UnMerge

       

    'Delete Columns A1 thru D1

    Range("$A$1:$D$1").EntireColumn.Delete

   

    'Delete Rows A1 thru A9

    Range("$A$1:$A$9").EntireRow.Delete

 

    'Cut and Paste Cells

    Range("$A$2").Cut Range("$A$1")

    Range("$G$1").Cut Range("$F$1")

    Range("$P$1").Cut Range("$O$1")

    Range("$AA$1").Cut Range("$Z$1")

 

    'Sort by Column A to Remove Extra Rows from View

    Columns("$A:$AM").Sort key1:=Range("$A:$A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

 

    'Auto Fit Contents in Columns and Rows

    ActiveCell.Columns("$A:$AG").EntireColumn.Select

    ActiveCell.Columns("$A:$AG").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit

   

    'Delete Empty Columns

    Range("$B:$B, $D:$D, $G:$I, $K:$L, $N:$N, $P:$Q, $T:$V, $X:$Y, $AA:$AB, $AD:$AF").EntireColumn.Delete

  

    'Remove Wrap Text from Cell B1

    Range("$B$1").WrapText = False

   

    'Autofit Contents of Columns

    Range("$A$1:$AF$1").Columns.AutoFit

   

    'Autofit Row A2 Contents

    Range("$A$2:$A$2").Rows.AutoFit

   

    'Delete Columns B and C

    Range("$B:$C").EntireColumn.Delete

   

    'Remove Wrap Text on L1 and M1

    Range("$L$1:$M$1").WrapText = False

 

    'Label Cell L1

    Range("$L$1").Value = "Qty from Previous Report"

   

    'Label Cell M1

    Range("$M$1").Value = "Change in Qty"

   

    'Label Cell N1

    Range("$N$1").Value = "Date New"

   

    'Label Cell O1

    Range("$O$1").Value = "Comments"

   

    'Label Cell P1

    Range("$P$1").Value = "Action"

   

    'Label Cell Q1

    Range("$Q$1").Value = "Status"

   

    'Label Cell R1

    Range("$R$1").Value = "Production Storage Quantity"

   

    'Autofit Contents of Columns

    Range("$L$1:$R$1").Columns.AutoFit

   

      

    'Open Previous Day Source file from User Selection   

    Dim val As String

    Dim intChoice As Integer

    Dim strPath1 As String

   

    'Alert User to open file

    MsgBox ("Please browse to the previous day Audit file you wish to use for the VlookUp")

   

    'Open File Dialog Box

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

  

    'Open File Dialog Box and prompt User to select single file

    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

 

    'Determine what file User selected

    If intChoice <> 0 Then

 

    'Get File Path selected by User

    strPath1 = Application.FileDialog( _

    msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

 

   'VLookup Column L thru R and Paste to Target File

   ‘This is where I need to take the file opened at the very beginning, and look up value A2, from the new    

   ‘file the user just opened, from Sheet 1! A:L, col index 12, FALSE, and paste into column L2 in the file

   ‘opened from the beginning, to the last row that has data (last row containing data changes each

   ‘time).

  ‘I need to then do the same for M-R, changing the col index to 13 for M, 14 for O, so forth and so on,    

  ‘and end each look up to the last row with data in the column.

  ‘I need to be able to IFERROR,0 in my steps to avoid #n/a

  ‘I then to need to copy and paste the values I just entered from row 2 – L:R, to last Row of data, and

  ‘paste value.

 

   'Save File As

    Application.GetSaveAsFilename

    End If

   

    'Notify User of Incompatible File

ErrorFileIncompatiable:

    MsgBox "This is not an Audit Report"

    Exit Sub

    End If

   

   

End Sub
```

[Results destination file macro after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lzAY.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lzAY.jpg)

Comment: You dont need the `.Select` . For the first part you could use 
`Option Compare Text` (Not case sensitive) and just  `If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*Audit*"` then`. Why do you need a vlookup? You just seem to copy and paste values into another workbook. For Lastrow use sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` (Note: sht has to be declared as the worksheet you  want to use)

Comment: The copy and paste steps steps are independent and occur before the opening of the second sheet, where the vlookup needs to occur. After completing the copy and paste formatting steps, I need to call open another file, and complete the vlookup. The problem that I have is knowing which sheet is active and being able to recall the source and destination files separately that's why I was thinking that I may need a variable as the name of the file changes and it is never named the same week after week.

Comment: It would be good if you add a before and after screenshot with junk data.

Comment: I guess I dont understand. A before and after shot of what?   All the steps are correct above, I just need where you see in the commented section of my code, to understand, after calling open the file from the file dialog box, how to refer to it (as the name will not be static, and change week after week) in a Vlookup. This macro runs on one file the user will have open, prior to running the macro. I did not program that either, as again, file name changes week after week.

Comment: They start with an audit report open. Run macro. Macro cleans file from export out of another reporting system (not excel based, or other I can access). Macro performs the copy and paste and deletion steps you see to format the file from the original version, as it is a mess. It cleans up the format and creates placeholder columns for the vlookup.  Then I have the user open a second file (source file) that they select, to use for the vlookup that will need to be performed with the end result placed in the original open file. How to start vlookup from file user selects if I dont know name?

Comment: I didnt understand why you want to use a vlookup. Thats why i would like to see an example of data how it look before your macro and how it should be after using it. See my post, how you could start with the vlookup.

Comment: I have to use a vlookup after the formatting is done, as I have to take the newly formatted file, and vlookup column a2 from formatted file, in a new file the user opens, and return the value it finds,  in A:l of newly open file, returning value from column index 12, false. I have to vlookup to get the data from one file to the next. There are two different files open. There is a file that is open manually by the user, then the user runs this macro to clean that file formatting. Then it prompts the user to open a second file, and it is to perform the vlookup, looking up a value..

Comment: In the original open file, into the second file, and returning the value from the newly opened second file, and pasting it into the original file. I think you may think I only have one file open, or something, but there is a file open before any steps run. That is what is being formatted. My issue is, both file names change every day. It basically starts with data exported into excel of the current day, cleans it up, and copies over (by vlookup) data from the previous day or last time the report was pulled, and places it into the new day file. But every day, the file names for both files chang

Comment: They change based on date, and even user who pulls files, as the other program incorporates the user name. I cannot make modifications to the way the file is saved or named. Nor can I pull it myself from the source or link to it

Comment: Its very hard to follow you. Look at my answers, you should be able to perfrom your vlookup with it.

Comment: I guess I dont know how it is hard to follow. Ive outlined the steps and process.  I have to finish the vlookup part of the VBA code, and am having trouble as both files are named dynamic. I.e. change every day. So I cant "hard code" the file names in.

Comment: Im just trying to understand how you can programmatically create a vlookup between two files when each time you run the macros the name of the file changes daily for both files. Thus why I was relying on the user to have the "destination" file open first before running the macro, and relying on them to open the second file otherwise referred to as the "Source" file, when promoted by the dialog box.

Comment: I think you should probably have a master file and then the user selects the first file to clean up and then the second one to compare. then you can open up both files and work with them.

Comment: you store the workbooks in different variables and then adress them like i did below. you are thinking way to complicated and thats why its hard to follow you.

Comment: So make a third file? I guess I dont understand this logic when they can simoly take the exported file and run the macro on it and clean it up. Macro will be installed of their personal macro file, with toolbar shortcut. They wont need to do anything but open the exported daily file, and hit the button, and it will clean it. Then they are prompted to open second file (previous day, source file) and the macro should be able to take a2 of the destination (first file) and compare it to a:l of the source file (second file they opened from my dialog box), and return the value in "Q" (12), false

Comment: Im more of a workflow writer, and it us a different animal all together.

Comment: Im trying to follow your example. Ive added your code, and now adding the array, etc...  I need to copy it down to the last row containing text. Which will vary day by day.  How do I make it perform this lookup and end it or copy the formula to every cell in the column, ending at the last row it that contains text?

Comment: So you want to check if the value in Col `A` and the correspoding row of the data set is in the opened file in `range("A:I")`. If so return the value in Col `Q`.

Comment: I want to check if value in column a in first original file is found in file opened by dialog box within range A thru L, and if so... return value in Q and place it into original file column L. Then I want to extend this vlookup formula to every cell for every row that contains text, within L. Then I want to copy, paste just the value of L, removing the lookup. Also, if I  could Iferror or other to remove any "#N/A" , it may create. Then I want to move to column M, look up A2, in same range, and this time return R, so forth and so on until column R of original sheet returning W or 18 so to spe

Comment: You really mean `A2` and not `B`? i updated my answer, it will go trough col `A` and paste the value into col `L` . As i said its hard to help you with the informations you provide. you are thinking way to complicated, you dont need to paste in formulas, you can just print out the values. Thats why i asked for screenshot, to evaluate any easier solution than the one you are thinking of. you can do way more in vba than you probably think of.

Comment: No. I need just their values in the column. No formulas. This file will be part of a SharePoint workflow doing other tasks, after this step. I need only the values in the cells, the equivalent of copying and paste special, values. I do not want the vlookup formula to remain in the destination cell. Just the value it copies from the source. I want it to return blank if no value is found, thus the iferror, 0 or some how remove the #N/A it returns when it cannot match. Im not simply pasting values from the former sheet into the columns, im looking up A in the source sheet, row by row

Comment: you dont get my point. i said it can be done directly, you wanted to do it in 2 steps. you dont need any copy paste. but anyway, just try my code it will do that for row a. try and adjust to match the columns.

Comment: Im trying it. Im havimg trouble adjusting the statement. Im not sure how to format my cell, range, 12, false..

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with this:

```
    Option Compare Text

Sub AuditRptCleanup()
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Verify Correct File Is Open
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*Audit*" Then

    'Verify Macro has not ran on Workbook Previously

    With sht

    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Product Number" And .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Prod Type" Then

    MsgBox "Macro has already been used on this workbook"

    Exit Sub

    End If


    'Unmerge all Cells in Worksheet
    .Cells.UnMerge

    'Delete Columns A1 thru D1
    .Range("$A$1:$D$1").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Delete Rows A1 thru A9
    .Range("$A$1:$A$9").EntireRow.Delete


    'Cut and Paste Cells
    .Range("$A$2").Cut .Range("$A$1")
    .Range("$G$1").Cut .Range("$F$1")
    .Range("$P$1").Cut .Range("$O$1")
    .Range("$AA$1").Cut .Range("$Z$1")

    'Sort by Column A to Remove Extra Rows from View
    .Columns("$A:$AM").Sort key1:=.Range("$A:$A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    'Auto Fit Contents in Columns and Rows
    .Columns("$A:$AG").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit

    'Delete Empty Columns
    .Range("$B:$B, $D:$D, $G:$I, $K:$L, $N:$N, $P:$Q, $T:$V, $X:$Y, $AA:$AB, $AD:$AF").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Remove Wrap Text from Cell B1
    .Range("$B$1").WrapText = False

    'Autofit Contents of Columns
    .Range("$A$1:$AF$1").Columns.AutoFit

    'Autofit Row A2 Contents
    .Range("$A$2:$A$2").Rows.AutoFit

    'Delete Columns B and C
    .Range("$B:$C").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Remove Wrap Text on L1 and M1
    .Range("$L$1:$M$1").WrapText = False

    'Label Cell L1
    .Range("$L$1").Value = "Qty from Previous Report"

    'Label Cell M1
    .Range("$M$1").Value = "Change in Qty"

    'Label Cell N1
    .Range("$N$1").Value = "Date New"

    'Label Cell O1
    .Range("$O$1").Value = "Comments"

    'Label Cell P1
    .Range("$P$1").Value = "Action"

    'Label Cell Q1
    .Range("$Q$1").Value = "Status"

    'Label Cell R1
    .Range("$R$1").Value = "Production Storage Quantity"

    'Autofit Contents of Columns
    .Range("$L$1:$R$1").Columns.AutoFit

    End With
    'Open Previous Day Source file from User Selection
    Dim val As String
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath1 As String

    'Alert User to open file
    MsgBox ("Please browse to the previous day Audit file you wish to use for the VlookUp")

    'Open File Dialog Box
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

    'Open File Dialog Box and prompt User to select single file
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    'Determine what file User selected
    If intChoice <> 0 Then

    'Get File Path selected by User
    strPath1 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    'VLookUp
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim j As Integer: j = 12
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(strPath1)
    Set sht2 = wb.Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet in WB adjust if needed

    xl.Visible = True

    lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To lRow
    If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Set rng = sht2.Range("A:A").Find(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            sht.Cells(i, 12).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 12).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 13).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 13).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 14).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 14).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 15).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 15).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 16).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 16).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 17).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 17).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 18).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 18).Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Data Found in Source File for A" & i)
        End If
    End If
    Next

   'Save File As
    wb.Close
    xl.Quit
    MsgBox ("Look Up Done")
    End If

Else
MsgBox "This is not an Audit Report"
End If
End Sub
```

As i already mentioned i would use `Option Compare Text` to check for the right file. Other than that i deleted the `On Error Statement` because it didnt make much sense there. I included an `Else` Statement instead.

Comment: I guess I dont understand why a third file would be necessary. Cant I just somehow get the file name saved to a variable from the open.file input from the dialog box?

Comment: i do that, you did it too.

Comment: From the destination file, and returning the value from Q in the source file, and putting that value in L.  And filling in all cells in column L with their results. Looking up A3, returning the value in Q when found, A4, etc etc. In other words if I did it manually, I would be dragging the lookup and copying it into all of L, and then selecting L:L and pasting just the value, to remove the formula.

Comment: I have it looking like:

Comment: Actually it looks a mess

Comment: try this code and tell me if it does what you want.

Comment: .vlookup(Range("A2"), Sheets(1).Range("A:L"), 12, False)      which isn't yielding the results I need  it keeps telling me it needs an operator. So then I changed it to [L2] = ... the rest of the worksheetfunction statement you wrote. It took it without error... did not produce any result

Comment: you are not adressing the ranges of the different workbooks correctly.

Comment: First.. let me first say, although it may not convey in my messages, I reallllllyyyyyy appreciate your help, and knowledge. I know this has taken time, and I am thankful for you.

Comment: I added what you wrote and it errors at set wb statement. 424

Comment: Please make a copy of your workbook and exchange the whole sub with mine and try again.

Comment: I did that. Vlookup is not pasting any values in destination file L column. Nothing. No errors, no nothing. It is not prompting me to save file, so I dont think it is completing the vlookup.  It doesnt give any 1004 errors or other. Just makes formatting changes and stops.

Comment: It prompts me to open the sorce file, but it is like it doesnt really open it. It isnt open after running the macro either.

Comment: i took the part out where it asks to save the file. the only thing why it isnt doing anything is, that there are no values in col a or the values are not in the second sheet.

Comment: if there are any error, or not found it will move on to the next value in col a.

Comment: It isnt the second sheet. It is the first sheet of the newly opened workbook file (Source). Pasting the value of that sheet, into the workbook we have open (destination) prior to starting the workflow. If it just doing one cell, then the result is blank. If we having it continuing down the entire column of A, pasting the "Q" value into the destunation file L column, until it hits the last row that has text, the results are no good, and it is not working, as every single cell in Column L in the destination file is blank.

Comment: What? it is checking col a for the values and looking there for the lastrow. there has to be a value in row 2 and onwards. if theres none it wont look up any values. i dont know how your sheets looking so i could test it on my own. you can go trough the code with f8 and see whats its doing.

Comment: In the first A2 of Destination file look up, to A2 of source file, return source Q, into destination L, it is blank. Each cell in column L is blank. So it is not just finding no value. It is not working. If it wasnt finding a value to match, it would go to next. There is 0 probability that non of the lookups match. Ive dine it manually and row 2, 6, and so on, have a match abd should return a value

Comment: The file we open is the source. The file open before the macro begins is the destination. There are 2 files in use. We should be comparing A2 of destination, to A:L of the source, and returning the value of Q of source, into destination L3.  If no match, it should then move to A3, compare and move down until L is filled until the last row that contains text. It should stop, not vlookup passed rows that do not have data

Comment: i exchanged the vlookup with a more suitable solution. try it out and tell me if it works.

Comment: Ok. I think I have confused you. I need to lookup ever value in column A of my desination  file (starting with A2), into the source file I open with Macro. I need to look for value in array of source file a:L, and return 12th column value = L in this case (as 12=L) and paste the value from L of the source into the destination. I should do this for every single cell in column L in destination file, until it hits a blank row (thus indicating the end of the data). Each row should check the value in A, and look for it in source, and return 12(L). Then it needs to move onto M, and 13, O, and 14,

Comment: So forth and so on. It is a basic look up. Look for a part number in a, find it in previous days report, return the value it finds when matched from that row, and place it in L. Then move on down the line right, until it reaches 18 or R so to speak.filling the columns. If no value, then it should be blank, not #N/A

Comment: So the destination and source cells are vice versa or what? i dont really get the point. But as it seems it looking working but with the wrong values?  you should be able to adjust it then or not?

Comment: I guess I dont understand what it is doing above. It doesnt move to a different column to get a value for L if one cannot be found. It literally skips it, finishes all rows in the sheet that contain data, so.. it goes from A2 to end of last row, and then goes to M, and looks for A2 and returns M, to M2, and goes on down the columns, then goes to N, so forth and so on.

Comment: The destination is the file I open.. BEFORE running the macro. It isnt identified by any step, with the exception of making sure it is an audit file. The file we open with the macro is the source file. We are not inputting any information there, that is the array and columns we are coping information from in our vlookup. Then we are pasting the value into column L of the destination file. If this was done manually. It would be entered in L2 of destination file, A2, A2 source file sheet 1, 12, False. Then you would double click to extend the lookup to the last row containing text.

Comment: It is a regular run of the mill vlookup. I just need to automate the step for the macro, and look up L,M,N,O,P,Q,R based on A2 and return the value of L to L, M to M, N to N, Etc etc

Comment: So what it does is, it checks `A2` for the last set of data. in the `for` loop from `2 to lastrow` it will check the values of `A & i` and checks if they match with any value in the file opened in `Range("A:L")`. if so it will copy the values from `q to w` of the source file to `l to r` of the destination file. all at once.

Comment: What do you want to look up in `l to r`? before you said `a to l`. now its the same rows?

Comment: The value to compare will be a to a. That is where product number is found im both source and destination file. I said A to L as I just used that as the array...  but it literally will be looking for A cell by cell, finding the number in A column of source, and returning, yes, L to R of the matched row, and pasting the values into L to R of the other sheet,,omitting any #N/A! On the way.. and leaving those blanks. I was unaware I could do it at once

Comment: But it doesnt perform any lookuops it isnt erroring.. but it isnt working either. It leaves l,m,n,o,p,q,r are all blank. No values in any cell, after running macro :( but doesnt throw any 1004 errors or other.

Comment: It now gives a messagebox for the row where it does not find a match. There are only two options if it does not copy anything. the rows in the source file are emtpy or no match. go trought the code line by line and see what if it matches.

Comment: Same result. I run macro, it completes all formatting steps, prompts to open the file (second file/source file), it acts like it is going to open, dialog disappears from screen, it isnt open in any window, and the macro is done, but no look ups were completed, no errors were thrown, no message box either that you just added. Is it having a hard time with the strpath1 ? I dont understand how it just sits stagnant. It acts like it has completed.. but nothing... grrrrr!!!.

Comment: Now it throws a message box after the look up. Have you gone trough the code with f8? then you should also see if it opens the workbook. is the data in the data in the source file in the first workhsheet?

Comment: Ok. Worksheet is Sheet1.  I used F8, and it goes all steps (although it doesnt seem like it opens the file.. it goes threw the actions of, but I dont see it actually open, then it completes all steps but hita For i statement, theb skips to wb.close, end if, end it, end sub. It is like it never opens the file, and then skips the If Not rng Is Nothing Then and corresponding steps. I want to beat my laptop with a bat, like a printer from the movie Office Space. Lol. Hopefully you know the reference. :)

Comment: Thats strage, have you tried different files? You can comment out the close statement and then check if the file is opened. What the excel version you are woking with? Could you try it out on a different machine? And i dont know the reference, probably too young

Comment: It is a movie, very funny, about a tech company, and they want to destroy the fax machine with a baseball bat because no matter what they do it states PC Load letter...  anyways, worth the youtube or google.  As for the macro Im on Excel 2010/office 2010 suite. I have opened and closed and used repeated files, it literally acts like it opens the second file (as in it goes through the motions of.. letting you select and hit open) but I dont think it is really opening.  It is also skipping the other statements/declarations/arguements, whatever you call them .. anything under IF Not rng Is Nothin

Comment: Could you go trough again and check the value of lastrow? You can hover it and it will tell you the value

Comment: And just comment out the `On Error` statement.

Comment: My value of lRow = 1 when I hover over it. Unless you meant something different.

Comment: This means, that there is no Data in A2 and below. So nothing it can look up and the reason it skips this part. And thats not an error of my code. Something with your formatting is wrong then.

Comment: That is incorrect :( I guess it is not referencing the right sheet. Please understand, literally no cell has value that should have result in it. Not 1. There is no possible way, no value from column A destination sheet, does not match value in source A..  no way at all.

Comment: I dont have enough "reputation points" to post images.. what the heck. How can I show you this. Honest to God there is 0 way, all values in A do not match A in the source sheet. The first may not match, but many do. Ive completed tge vlookup manually and I can prove it. It is not looking in A of file we open, and is not returning L to R into L to R, based on matching A, into destination. All entries in all columns l to r are blank in our starting file. I wish I could show you the screenshoots, I think you would understand better what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: The user opens a file (which we will refer to as the destination file). They do not have any other files open, what so ever.   They then run the macro.  Macro cleans up destibation file formatting issues. Macro then  prompts them to open second file (which is the previous day or last ran report) we shall refer to this as the source file. User is prompted by open file dualog, and selects file, presses open. Macro is then to take value is destination A starting with first row (so A2) and match it to any occurence in A column of source file. When it finds it, it is to return the values of l to r

Comment: And paste the values into l to R of the destination file. If a value is #N/A! It should not put #N/A rather iferror(0) or blank, and go to next. It should then check A3, and find it, and return L to R, so forth so on, till last row that contains text.. which row will change each time ran. That is it.

Comment: you can post images in your question but only the links. lRow checks column a for values if its 1 then there are no values in a2. Please add the images.

Comment: Or does it need to perform the look up before the formatting?

Comment: It formats the destination file first. It has to. It needs to edit out bad formatting from being exported from a 3rd party application. It must be cleaned up and column l to R created to hold the values from vlookup results.

Comment: All formatting steps are applicable to destination file we have open at start of this process, before even running macro. Macro fomats, then calls open the second file (source file) which contains the data we need to place into the newly created columns of destination file.

Comment: Please add images of the source file and the destination after formatting.

Comment: The source is called open, but it never really opens. I am uploading a source photo.. but this isnt a screenshot of it opening from macro. This is me manually opening it, after file has ran. The yellow columns are those we need to place the value of, in the destination file, as a result of matching A to A, from destinatiom, to source, with our vlookup. The other photo is the destination file, after performing macro. I cant add anymore than 2 links as I am new, which is unfortunate, as I could show you before of destination so you can see, it is running the formatting steps, and not the vlookup

Comment: If you take any value (well not the first in a2 as it truly not in source sheet) but if you take any value in column a of destination and match it into source A, you will see there are several matches. If you performed the vlookup manually, there is a whole bunch that should be copying over. I shouls not have a fully blank result.

Comment: Exchange `lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ` with `lRow = 20` and test if it does anything

Comment: This macro needs to take from destination file, match A line by line, (So start with A2, and proceed if not matched, or return result if matched, and go to next line), and look it up in the file we open (Source), and return results of L to R in source, into L to R of destination file.

Comment: I did replace.. nothing. Result blank. I swear even though it prompts me to open the other file, it isnt opening it, or if it is, it is not using that file for the vlookup. Could it be stuck thinking to reference itself, thus why it is returning all blanks, as it is looking for A2 in the same file, and returning l to r which is already blank, thus thinking it is working? It isnt throwing any errors, but it literally is not adding any values in L to R of my starting file. It isnt copying it from that file we call open with application.filedialog

Comment: Comment out the `On Error` Statement.

Comment: Ok. Also.. should the file we open, be open when the macro ends, or is it set to close after the look up. All I am left with after it runs, is just my starting destination file. No other file opens, or is open at end of macro but file I started with.

Comment: As I said comment out `On Error Resume Next` and `wb.Close`

Comment: Commented out on error. When it ends, all cells are selected. Entire sheet of the destination file is selected. No results though. Prompts me to open file, still nothing, no values are vlook up and matched and carried over into l to r. L to r is blank. Every row.

Comment: And there are no error messages? Can you go trough with f8 again? Is there any other vba code executing? i dont know why its not doing anything for you, its working for me.

Comment: Sure I will check it. No.. there is not any other VBA going on. It just does not work. It runs all formatting steos, opens the file dialog to get the file, I select it, click open.. nothing. No error no nothing. I will F8

Comment: Ok. I F8 through code, no errors, it executes line by line..  it prompts me to open the file, I select the previous day file, press open, but Im telling you..  I dont think it actually opens it, as after hitting f8, no new window is open with that file in it. Not even for a split second. All that is open is my original file and the debugger... nothing else

Comment: Try the edited code. it opens a new application. with f8 should be able to see the workbook open.

Answer (score 0):

Before the user runs the macro, they will:

Step 1. Open current day audit report
Step 2. Run macro (to format)
Step 3. Macro should prompt user to open previous day or last used audit file from dialog box 
Step 4. Lookup A2 of current day report, in previous day report, and return whatever is in column Q, and paste that value in current day report line by line, starting with A2, then A3, then A4, so forth and so on, until hitting an empty row (or last row with text). It should then look up A2 again, but this time, return value R in source, into row M of destination file, so forth and so on, until Row R of destination is full.

Comment: I commented out the on error, still same result. It is as if it isnt truly opening the file I am selecting. It goes through the motions, but I never see it open. And if it is really opening, it surely isnt performing any action, vlookup, match or other with it. I am going to mock up 2 files, and show you is screenshots. Only way I think I can better explain

Answer (score 0):

I have done that, and now it is giving me the good ole' "Compile Error"..  block if without end if, and highlighting end sub, last line in our macro.  It does lRow=20 then next line (since all others are commented out)..

Else
MsgBox "This is not an Audit Report"
End If
End Sub

It is the end sub it is highlighting

Answer (score 0):

It then goes to If intChoice <> 0 Then
    strPath1 = Application.FileDialog       (msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

And skips all statements/variable/Dim but.. goes directly from mso statement to
Dim j As Integer:  j = 12

Then skips next line and goes to

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath1)
Set sht2 = wb.Worksheets (1)
lRow = 20
End If
End If
Exit Sub
```

Comment: That literally skipped all my formatting steps, prompted me to open file, and said look up done, and file was left in original state as before macro was ran. It didnt fornat, it skipped right to opening file 3 times, and had me open it, and directly after pressing open, it said look up done. Which.. it did nothing. No values. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Workbook. Call it audit.xlsm. Paste in this code:

```
    Option Compare Text

Sub AuditRptCleanup()
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Verify Correct File Is Open
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*Audit*" Then

    'Verify Macro has not ran on Workbook Previously

    With sht

    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Product Number" And .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Prod Type" Then

    MsgBox "Macro has already been used on this workbook"

    Exit Sub

    End If


    'Unmerge all Cells in Worksheet
    .Cells.UnMerge

    'Delete Columns A1 thru D1
    .Range("$A$1:$D$1").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Delete Rows A1 thru A9
    .Range("$A$1:$A$9").EntireRow.Delete


    'Cut and Paste Cells
    .Range("$A$2").Cut .Range("$A$1")
    .Range("$G$1").Cut .Range("$F$1")
    .Range("$P$1").Cut .Range("$O$1")
    .Range("$AA$1").Cut .Range("$Z$1")

    'Sort by Column A to Remove Extra Rows from View
    .Columns("$A:$AM").Sort key1:=.Range("$A:$A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    'Auto Fit Contents in Columns and Rows
    .Columns("$A:$AG").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit

    'Delete Empty Columns
    .Range("$B:$B, $D:$D, $G:$I, $K:$L, $N:$N, $P:$Q, $T:$V, $X:$Y, $AA:$AB, $AD:$AF").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Remove Wrap Text from Cell B1
    .Range("$B$1").WrapText = False

    'Autofit Contents of Columns
    .Range("$A$1:$AF$1").Columns.AutoFit

    'Autofit Row A2 Contents
    .Range("$A$2:$A$2").Rows.AutoFit

    'Delete Columns B and C
    .Range("$B:$C").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Remove Wrap Text on L1 and M1
    .Range("$L$1:$M$1").WrapText = False

    'Label Cell L1
    .Range("$L$1").Value = "Qty from Previous Report"

    'Label Cell M1
    .Range("$M$1").Value = "Change in Qty"

    'Label Cell N1
    .Range("$N$1").Value = "Date New"

    'Label Cell O1
    .Range("$O$1").Value = "Comments"

    'Label Cell P1
    .Range("$P$1").Value = "Action"

    'Label Cell Q1
    .Range("$Q$1").Value = "Status"

    'Label Cell R1
    .Range("$R$1").Value = "Production Storage Quantity"

    'Autofit Contents of Columns
    .Range("$L$1:$R$1").Columns.AutoFit

    End With
    'Open Previous Day Source file from User Selection
    Dim val As String
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath1 As String

    'Alert User to open file
    MsgBox ("Please browse to the previous day Audit file you wish to use for the VlookUp")

    'Open File Dialog Box
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

    'Open File Dialog Box and prompt User to select single file
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    'Determine what file User selected
    If intChoice <> 0 Then

    'Get File Path selected by User
    strPath1 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    'VLookUp
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim j As Integer: j = 12
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(strPath1)
    Set sht2 = wb.Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet in WB adjust if needed

    xl.Visible = True

    sht.Cells(2, 1).Value = "F"
    sht.Cells(3, 1).Value = "H"
    lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To lRow
    If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Set rng = sht2.Range("A:A").Find(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            sht.Cells(i, 12).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 12).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 13).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 13).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 14).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 14).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 15).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 15).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 16).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 16).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 17).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 17).Value
            sht.Cells(i, 18).Value = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 18).Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Data Found in Source File for A" & i)
        End If
    End If
    Next

   'Save File As
    wb.Close
    xl.Quit
    MsgBox ("Look Up Done")
    End If

Else
MsgBox "This is not an Audit Report"
End If
End Sub
```

Then create another workbook. call it audit2.xlsx.  Make it look like this: 
[image]

Then Run the code and choose audit2.xlsx as workbook to open.

Expected Result: 
[image]

Comment: Ok. I did just that and it produced same end result. The only difference between this and the other, is my macro is not stored in the file, rather Im calling it from my personal macro workbook. I cannot store it in each file, I need a central location where I can call it from, as well as have a methodology to "install" it (aka assign it to users toolbar, and place into their personal macro workbook) for recall when we want to use it. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yep.. thats it. When I put the macro into the actual workbook, it works. It tells me 1000 times certain values cant be found, but it works, well until Q. It does not do R column, and I need it to expand to R.  When I try to execute from personal workbook, it doesnt work. I need this written to be stored in a personal workbook. The files used both audit and audit2 from your example or source and destination from my perspective change day by day. I cant have users needing to copy and paste macros into workbooks. I need to be able to install it on their computers by copying and pasting it

Comment: Into their personal macro workbook. I need it to work from that perspective. Then all they need to do is open their current audit report, and run macro to clean it, select other file, it will vlookup, and they can save the finished end product

Comment: Ok. So when it pastes, is there a way to have the text arial unicode  8 pt? It adds the value in a different font size. I can clean uo formatting after if need be, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it, during the lookup.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Al30ey-vmWkFgTHMt4es2ABDz6t0 Download this and you can add it as an Add-In. It will add a ribbon to start it from every workbook. This is a tutorial how to add it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-add-ins-0af570c4-5cf3-4fa9-9b88-403625a0b460

Comment: it will change the font size now.

Comment: I found the issue and fixed it :) believe it or not, it had an issue with the first thisWorkbook, as it is the personal workbook. I changed that to Set sht =ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet. and had no problems. Then I added in a

Comment: Same thing i had to for the addin. You can look in to the code for how to change the font

Comment: Im not seeing what you changed. I must be overlooking something

Comment: `With sht.Range("L:R").Font` `.Size =8` `.Name = "Arial"` `End With`

Comment: Ive stuck myself in a never ending loop of end if issues when I tweaked this..  it is highlighting end sub, last line with a compile error.. "For without Next"...  ughhh... ::face palm::: so close so far away..  ughh.. i just need to size a few column widths and prompt them to save it, and this is done.

Comment: Put the with under the for loop

Comment: ...and I fixed it!!! Woohoo! Lol :) Thank you a zillion times over for your help.